Extension of a tangent vector field
Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $S^2$ with $\overline{\Omega} \neq S^2$. Suppose a continuous tangent vector field $G$ is defined on $\partial \Omega$ such that $|G(y)| = 1$ for all $y \in \partial \Omega$.
Under what conditions can one guarantee the existence of a continuous tangent vector field $F$ on $\overline{\Omega}$ such that $|F(x)| = 1$ for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$ and $F = G$ on $\partial \Omega$? I would appreciate any hints or references.

Since the closure $\overline\Omega$ cannot be the whole sphere, we can assume that $\Omega$ is an open subset of the plane. Unit vector fields on the plane are in one-to-one correspendence with the mappings to the circle. A map from $\partial\Omega$ to $S^1$ determines a 1-cocycle in $H^1(\partial\Omega).$ I suggest that one should take Čech or Alexander-Spanier cohomology but don't sure. I think this question is more suited for algebraic topology tag. The image of this cocycle in $H^2(\Omega, \partial\Omega)$ is trivial if and only if the map can be extended to the whole $\Omega.$
